# How to exit out of password mode?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

If I Ctrl+C on a password prompt in shell (for eg during an scp or ssh), the shell is forever gone into the hidden characters (password) mode. There appears to be no way for me to start echoing the keystrokes to the display again and I have to logoff and log back in. Is there a simple way to force shell out of the password mode so that I can execute other commands?

This might be answered somewhere else (or might have a simple answer) but I cannot come up with suitable search terms that tell me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever there is something wrong with the terminal, usually one of `reset` or `stty sane` will get it back to a usable state. Which it is depends on the problem at hand.

Comment: Great!!! `reset` did it for me too. I am using the bash terminal of git inside of Visual Studio Code in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Try typing `reset`, it should (As the command implies) reset the terminal.